# probability combinations of criket selection county

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A local cricket county invited players from two neighbouring towns Norwich, Ipswich to form a cricket team of 11 players to participate in an upcoming cricket tournament. After selection process, it has shortlisted 22 players from both towns together and tagged each player skill points between 5 to 10 (both numbers included, only whole numbers are considered) based on their performance. The county has also categorised players into pool of batsmen, bowlers, wicket keepers and all-rounders. A player can only belong to one pool. Now the county has asked its final selection committee to pick 11 players from all shortlisted players following the below rules:

A minimum of 3 and a maximum of 6 batsmen must be selected.

A minimum of 3 and a maximum of 6 bowlers must be selected.
A minimum of 1 and a maximum of 4 Wicket Keeper must be selected.

A minimum of 1 and a maximum of 4 All-rounders must be selected.

A maximum of 7 players can be selected from each town.

Skill points of selected players combined must not exceed 100 points.

Can you help the selection committee to understand in how many ways they can pick final 11?